# What is the meaning of negated subjonctive, present and past, but without "pas"?

Tags: négation, subjonctif

I met this phrase:

> "Il ne tint pas à lui que nous n'ayons en France, 
>   dès 1908, les fameuses démonstrations de W. 
>   W. et que le prodigieux mouvement actuel n'ait 
>   commencé deux ans plus tôt".

Source: [L'Aerophile about Arnold Fordyce](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6552191k/f436.item.r=Arnold%20Fordyce.zoom)

Using historical facts (without apriori knowledge I would not have understood anything) I extracted a meaning from the above phrase as follows:

"It was something independent of him (it was not his fault) that we had (or witnessed) in France only (late) in 1908 the famous demonstrations of W.W. and (also) that the prodigios present movement has not started (or did not start) two years earlier (in 1906)." (This is my own interpretation, it can be wrong.)

However, I do not know why the present of subjonctive negated but without pas has the meaning of a positive and the past form of the same subjonctive also negated and without pas should be considered a negative.

Comment: It was not due to him that we had the famous WW demonstrations in France in 1908 and that the prodigious current movement had begun two years earlier. Dès means: as of or starting in. Or just IN.

Comment: Lambie, your version is more acurate than mine excepting the last word "earlier". It should be "later" otherwise from the historical point of view the phrase does not make sense. Is "que le mouvement n'ait commencé deux ans plus tôt" equivalent with "que le mouvement ait commencé deux ans plus tard"?

Comment: My reading is two-fold: the demonstrations started in 1908 and the movement started in 1906....the movement started two years earlier than the demonstrations. That makes sense, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Il s'agit d'un *ne* **explétif**.

> Le ne dit explétif se rencontre dans des propositions (phrases)
>   subordonnées introduites par la conjonction que (mot subordonnant) ou
>   par une locution conjonctive comportant que. Le ne explétif « est
>   appelé par des mots qui régissent, en règle générale, l’emploi du
>   subjonctif (sauf pour les subordonnées de comparaison) » (Gaatone,
>   1971, p. 81).

Il est **facultatif**, il ajoute une incertitude. Dans l'exemple cité, il aurait dû être évité:

> Il dépend de… que, il tient à… que
>
> Quand on utilise les formes impersonnelles il dépend de… que et il
>   tient à… que à la forme négative ou interrogative, on peut employer ou
>   omettre le ne explétif.
>
> Il ne dépendait pas de moi que cela se fît.
>
> ou
>
> Il ne dépendait pas de moi que cela ne se fît.
>
> Cela tient-il à moi qu’elle vienne?
>
> ou
>
> Cela tient-il à moi qu’elle ne vienne?
>
> **Dans un énoncé à la forme négative** introduit par il [ne] dépend ou il
>   [ne] tient que, on omettra le ne explétif si la connotation de la
>   subordonnée est positive.
>
> Il ne tient qu’au juge que cet avocat obtienne gain de cause quand
>   même.
>
> Il est toutefois possible que la subordonnée soit négative.
>   Évidemment, dans ce cas, on aura recours à ne pas (et non au ne
>   explétif).
>
> Il ne dépend que de moi que la fête n’ait pas lieu.

Tirés de [ce site](http://www.cce.umontreal.ca/observations/ne.htm).

Ce type d'arrangements est moins usité de nos jours, sauf pour donner une touche *ampoulée* à son récit. Et c'est assez difficilement compréhensible.

Answer (score 0):

Voir pages 173 à 187 dans 'le Français déchiffré, clé du langage et des langues' de Henri Adamcweski.

Chapitre intitulé: Ce NE qui en dit long...

Chapitre où il est démontré que ce 'ne' n'a jamais été bien expliqué d'où sa tendance à disparaître si l'on s'imagine , à tort, qu'il ne sert à rien!