# «ne vienne secouer la partie endormie de nous-même»?

Tags: grammaire

J’essaie de comprendre cette passage «jusqu’à ce qu’un évènement ne vienne secouer la partie endormie de nous-même et que nous avons volontairement contraint à un sommeil profond.»

Ce qui me confond c'est le mot 'ne' dans la phrase. Quelle est sa fonction?  Sans ce mot là, je traduirais la phrase de la façon suivante:«until an event came to shake that sleeping part of ourselves which we had volountarily restrict it to a deep sleep.»

Vous pouvez trouver le texte intégral à ce [site](http://fr.aleteia.org/2016/12/12/etes-vous-musulman-ou-chretien/?utm_campaign=NL_fr&utm_source=daily_newsletter&utm_medium=mail&utm_content=NL_fr).

Je vous remercie par avance.

Comment: La réponse [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/18189/1109)

Comment: Merci @jlliagre.